# gdb how to print variable name along with variable value like "$number = variable-name = variable-value"

Tags: gdb

By default, using `p variable-name` will display `$num = variable-value`, `$num` is the [value history](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Value-History.html), but it there a way to print the variable name along with the variable value like `$num = variable-name = variable-value`?

I want this since I use

```
define p
  set $i = 0
  while $i < $argc
    eval "print $arg%d", $i
    set $i = $i + 1
  end
end
```

in my ~/.gdbinit, to redefine p command so I can use `p var1 var2 var3...` to print multiple variables at once, but the print command only output `$num = variable-value`, and I don't know what the exact variable is in the output, the other situation is when I print the value history using just `p $num`, it is not that readable, I don't know the exact variable name.

**NOTE:** the variable may be int/char/pointer/array/vector/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to first add to the display list the wanted variables and then to display all of them together. Note that, it is needed to free the display list before with `undisplay`, otherwise it also prints the variables of the previous executions.

```
define p
  set confirm off
  eval "undisplay"
  set confirm on
  set $i = 0
  while $i < $argc
    eval "display $arg%d", $i
    set $i = $i + 1
  end
  display
end
```

The `undisplay` evaluation is enclosed between `set confirm off/on` to suppress the following message:

```
[answered Y; input not from terminal]
```

If you have already set the `confirm off` option in your ~/gdbinit file, you will need to remove these two lines.

**Edit:** Honestly, I came to know about the `display` command finding a solution for this question. Although this answer might be useful to print multiple variables with their respective names, after several days using `display` in my workflow, I discourage to use this answer since I have come to the conclusion that `display` itself fits better at least my needs (printing multiple variables at every stop). Here the [official doc](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto-Display.html):

> If you find that you want to print the value of an expression frequently (to see how it changes), you might want to add it to the automatic display list so that GDB prints its value each time your program stops. Each expression added to the list is given a number to identify it; to remove an expression from the list, you specify that number. The automatic display looks like this:
>   2: foo = 38
>   3: bar[5] = (struct hack *) 0x3804

Basically, I have started using the command like this: I add a variable with `display $var` to the list of variables, and every time a breakpoint is reached the listed variables are automatically printed. It makes sense to have a feature like this in gdb. Thanks @CodyChan for the motivation.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, we want to output

```
$num = variable-name = variable-value
```

instead of

```
$num = variable-value
```

As far as I can tell, gdb adds to the value history in only three places: the `print` command, the `call` command, and the `history-append!` Scheme function. Since my Scheme is rusty, we'll need to use the CLI or Python to run `print` and modify its output.

#### Using the CLI

```
define pp
  set $i = 0
  while $i < $argc
    eval "pipe print $arg%d | awk -v name='$arg%d' '{ if (NR == 1 && $2 == \"=\") { $2 = \"= \" name \" =\" }; print }'", $i, $i
    set $i++
  end
end
```

`Pipe` is new in gdb 10.

That awk command is, after unescaping,

```
awk -v name='$arg%d' '{ if (NR == 1 && $2 == "=") { $2 = "= " name " =" }; print }'
```

which changes the `=` (second field) in `$num = variable-value` to `= variable-name =` . If gdb's `print` command outputs more than one line, the `NR == 1` in the awk command makes sure the substitution is only done on the first line.

Security note: gdb's `pipe` command appears to parse the shell_command into tokens and uses `execve` to run it, rather than passing it to an actual shell. This prevents some code injection attacks (if, for instance, the `$arg%d` in `name='$arg%d'` contains single quotes), but you should be careful of running any shell command comprised of text you haven't vetted.

#### Using Python

```
class PP(gdb.Command):
  """print value history index, name, and value of each arg"""

  def __init__(self):
    super(PP, self).__init__("pp", gdb.COMMAND_DATA, gdb.COMPLETE_EXPRESSION)

  def invoke(self, argstr, from_tty):
    for arg in gdb.string_to_argv(argstr):
      line = gdb.execute("print " + arg, from_tty=False, to_string=True)
      line = line.replace("=", "= " + arg + " =", 1)
      gdb.write(line)

PP()
```

Here, we're using a more [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)-like approach, using `string.replace`.

Sample session:

```
(gdb) set args a b c
(gdb) start
Starting program: /home/mp/argprint a b c

Temporary breakpoint 2, main (argc=4, argv=0x7ffffffee278) at argprint.c:4
4               for(int i=0; i < argc; i++) {
(gdb) pp i argc argv argv[0]@argc
$1 = i = 0
$2 = argc = 4
$3 = argv = (char **) 0x7ffffffee278
$4 = argv[0]@argc = {0x7ffffffee49f "/home/mp/argprint", 0x7ffffffee4b1 "a", 0x7ffffffee4b3 "b", 0x7ffffffee4b5 "c"}
```